# Need assistance regarding auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

[image]

I placed a `UIView` of size `w=140, h=33` at position `x=16 ,y=20` and applied these constraints.

[image]

I want that `UIView` to display on half of the screen no matter what orientation or screen size is.

But the result is this in portrait orientation

[image]

And in landscape orientation the `UIView` vanish.

Why I am getting this behavior, In `autolayout` view width & height is calculated on bases of constraints.

Comment: Try setting the height constraint and removing the "bottom space" constraint

Comment: if you fix all constraint values then this will must happen. You need to set aspect ratio and proportional height or width constraint and need to handle differently for landscape. you r view vanishes in landscape because bottom constraint is 515 and in landscape mode if you place a view on a distance of 515 from bottom then it will be vanished.

Comment: take leading to superview, top to superview, proportional width to superview and aspect ratio to self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure out how to achieve exactly what you are looking for.
It's rather simple once you figure it out. Firstly, clear all you constraints. Position your UIView across all of the screen like so:

[image: View]

Then, add the constraints to be 0 to the Superview.

[image: Constariants]

**EDIT:** Now you need to use multiplier 2 to half the box size.

Then, go to the Size inspector, and select the Trailing Space to Superview and click edit. You'll be presented with the edit screen, where you will see the multiplier property. Set it to 0.5, and voila it'll go always to the middle of the screen.

[image: Superview]

Consider also adding a Height constraint, as if you don't the view get's compressed. It's fairly simple. The view will automatically update, and you'll  get this final result:
[image]

Hope that helps, Julian